# Delete fist column from all sheet except current sheet in excel

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I want to delete the first column(A:A) in each sheet except in the first or the current sheet. Can somebody help me.
I used the following code which deletes first column from each sheet.

```
Sub deletefirstcolum()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Sheets

    ws.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.Delete

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Please help. How do I exclude first or current sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an `If` condition on the worksheet:

```
Sub deletefirstcolum()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Sheets
        If Not ws Is ActiveSheet Then
            ws.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If

    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: I would prefer to use `ws.Columns(1).Delete`.  But this works +1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Test whether ws = to the active sheet:

```
Sub deletefirstcolum()
    Dim aWs As Worksheet
    Set aWs = ActiveSheet

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Sheets
        If aWs.Name <> ws.Name Then
            ws.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this. It deleted the column from the first sheet too